# Is Multiple APK and Build varient feature of Android same

Tags: android

Hi I am trying to understand the difference between Multiple APk and Build Variant Features of android .

Are this both same or different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of Multiple APK is different From Build Variants. Both are different and serve different purposes:

Multiple APK is for the single app distribution with multiple apks for multiple device configurations.

Developer docs say

> Multiple APK support is a feature on Google Play that allows you to publish different APKs for your application that are each targeted
>   to different device configurations. Each APK is a complete and
>   independent version of your application, but they share the same
>   application listing on Google Play and must share the same package
>   name and be signed with the same release key. This feature is useful
>   for cases in which your application cannot reach all desired devices
>   with a single APK.

where as the build variants are the mixture of your build types and build flavors.

> Build Variants: A build variant is a cross product of a build type and
>   product flavor, and is the configuration Gradle uses to build your
>   app. Using build variants, you can build the debug version of your
>   product flavors during development, or signed release versions of your
>   product flavors for distribution. Although you do not configure build
>   variants directly, you do configure the build types and product
>   flavors that form them. Creating additional build types or product
>   flavors also creates additional build variants. To learn how to create
>   and manage build variants, read the Configure build variants overview.

For More info refer https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html